# How to use TinyMessenger (Event Aggregator) With DI Container

Tags: c#, structuremap, eventaggregator

I was searching for a lightweight Event Aggregator for .Net and I stumbled upon TinyMessenger (https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger/wiki). It does seem to do the job that I want but I cannot figure out how to use it with a DI container e.g Structuremap that I intend to use.

Here is my simple test code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messageHub = new TinyMessengerHub();
        var salesMadeHandler = new SalesMadeHandler(messageHub);
        messageHub.Publish(new SaleMadeEvent() {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Total = 100});
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class SalesMadeHandler
{
    private readonly ITinyMessengerHub _messengerHub;
    public SalesMadeHandler(ITinyMessengerHub messengerHub)
    {
        _messengerHub = messengerHub;
        _messengerHub.Subscribe<SaleMadeEvent>(Handle);
    }

    public void Handle(SaleMadeEvent message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message Recieved with ID: " + message.Id);
    }
}
```

as you can see in the code above, I have a SalesMadeHandler class which is subscribing to the event in it's constructor. What I understand is that I should be able to mark this class with an Interface and the DI container should automatically create an instance of it and use it to handle the messages. However in this case I have to have an instance already created before publishing the message due to the subscription mechanism.

I think I am missing some key point here with Event Aggregates, can you please advise what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TinyIoC` as DI container. It works fine for the messenger and will create the messenger for you. To use it use have to install the `TinyIoC` nuget, open the file added to your project and uncomment `#define TINYMESSENGER` in the `Preprocessor Directives` region of the file.

Now you can use `TinyIoC` to resolve your instances and the DI container will create the messenger for you and pass it to your handler...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var salesMadeHandler = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<SalesMadeHandler>();

    var messageHub = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ITinyMessengerHub>();
    messageHub.Publish(new SaleMadeEvent() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Total = 100 });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Markus, the thing that is confusing me is the need to create a reference for salesMadeHandler in the code. If I am publishing this message across different bounded contexts, I cannot create instance of the handler class using any DI container. Instead my understanding is that when I publish the event/message the framework itself should invoke instance of the handler right?

Comment: Publishing the event will not create any instance for you. The messenger will only deliver when you subscribe. So you have to create at least one handler. `TinyIoC` supports singleton registration - but be careful using it, this can end up in a dependency-mess... Check out the docu of `TinyIoC` for how to create: https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/wiki/Registration---lifetimes#lifetimes